# Create node just to store properties of parent node

Tags: neo4j

Is it a good idea to create an add-on node to save extra properties?
Ex: user node, user data node. If user data is going to have a lot of data, will it help in memory optimization on queries involving only user node?

Or will it make no difference if we store all the data as properties in the parent node itself?

Comment: I do not think it makes a significant difference. Potentially how many properties are we talking about?

Comment: It depends a lot of your queries ! 
Neo4j stores all node's properties as a chain. So to get all the props of a user, it will be worse to have a `data user` node (because Neo4j needs to traverse a rel).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas right now there are very few properties(4-5). But it could potentially move to 500 to 600 properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Neo4j only for graph traversal + other DBMS for storing your 600 properties in convenient hierarchy (I mean document-based DBMS like MongoDB).

From my experience Neo4j is not very fast at lookups compared to MongoDB.
Also it is not that efficient at storage.

600 flat properties in every node looks like design mistake.

Also, you can look at hybrid Graph-Document solutions, like Arango or Orient. But I'm not sure for their reliability, for my projects I use Mongo+Neo4j.